# ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx failing to install on kubernetes 1.23.11

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I was trying to install nginx-ingress to kubernetes 1.23 with version 3.16.1 of ingress-nginx.
Note: The following was working in kubernetes 1.22.x .

I tried this

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
    
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx  --version 3.16.1 --kube-context test-context --namespace=internal-namespace
```

but I am getting this error:

```
  8 nginx.go:249] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"                                                                                                                                                          │

│ E0110 13:29:40.707682       8 reflector.go:127] k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource               │
│ E0110 13:29:41.998518       8 reflector.go:127] k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource               │
│ E0110 13:29:45.088906       8 reflector.go:127] k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource               │
│ E0110 13:29:50.400838       8 reflector.go:127] k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource               │
│ E0110 13:29:58.087390       8 reflector.go:127] k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource               │
│ E0110 13:30:11.090674       8 reflector.go:127] k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource               │
│ I0110 13:30:38.827033       8 main.go:187] "Received SIGTERM, shutting down"                                                                                                                                                             │
│ I0110 13:30:38.827071       8 nginx.go:365] "Shutting down controller queues"                                                                                                                                                            │
│ E0110 13:30:38.827377       8 store.go:178] timed out waiting for caches to sync                                                                                                                                                         │
│ I0110 13:30:38.827413       8 nginx.go:291] "Starting NGINX process"                                                                                                                                                                     │
│ I0110 13:30:38.827673       8 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease  ingress-namespace/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...                                                                                             │
│ I0110 13:30:38.827953       8 queue.go:78] "queue has been shutdown, failed to enqueue" key="&ObjectMeta{Name:initial-sync,GenerateName:,Namespace:,SelfLink:,UID:,ResourceVersion:,Generation:0,CreationTimestamp:0001-01-01 00:00:00 + │
│ I0110 13:30:38.827981       8 nginx.go:311] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"                                                                  │
│ I0110 13:30:38.839596       8 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-84bcfb76c7-q82gh"                                                                                                      │
│ I0110 13:30:38.848733       8 status.go:131] "removing value from ingress status" address=[20.227.15.7]                                                                                                                                  │
│ I0110 13:30:38.848778       8 nginx.go:373] "Stopping admission controller"                                                                                                                                                              │
│ I0110 13:30:38.848815       8 nginx.go:381] "Stopping NGINX process"                                                                                                                                                                     │
│ E0110 13:30:38.848912       8 nginx.go:314] "Error listening for TLS connections" err="http: Server closed"                                                                                                                              │
│ 2023/01/10 13:30:38 [notice] 44#44: signal process started                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ I0110 13:30:39.853244       8 nginx.go:394] "NGINX process has stopped"                                                                                                                                                                  │
│ I0110 13:30:39.853269       8 main.go:195] "Handled quit, awaiting Pod deletion"                                                                                                                                                         │
│ I0110 13:30:49.853602       8 main.go:198] "Exiting" code=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using an old Helm version, as with Kubernetes v1.22 `extensions/v1beta1`  is no longer served. You can read this up here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122

So, either use a new version, or emit the `--version` parameter and you should be fine.